# Не проходит обработка сообщений у телеграм бота

Tags: python, массивы, telegram-bot

бот сделан с помощью TeleBot.
Не проходит обработка данных массива и бот отправляет только слово "Данные: "

```
import telebot

a = ['Владимир Голубей 31311131', 'Василий Петрович']

i=()

bot = telebot.TeleBot("1248782796:AAGuSNnqLt00mtBiyWXVKPPmJW7H_L-f4HY")

kb1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
kb1.row('привет', 'пока')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'menu'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Рад вас видеть!", reply_markup=kb1)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):

    i = message.text.lower()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Данные: ', list(filter(lambda x:x.startswith(i),a))))


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['Владимир Голубей 31311131', 'Василий Петрович']
i = message.text.lower()
list(filter(lambda x:x.startswith(i),a))
```

Вы приводите строку, которую ищете, к нижнему регистру. А в тех строках, в которых вы её ищете, первые буквы - заглавные. Естественно, ничего не находится.

Можно поправить, например, так, если вам нужно искать регистро-независимо. Пусть всё будет в нижнем регистре - и то, что ищется, и то, в чём ищем:

```
list(filter(lambda x:x.lower().startswith(i),a))
```